# Simplest way to expand a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

What is the simplest way to forcibly expand a variable in a script such as this:

```
#!/bin/some
path=/nobackup/
sed -i "39s/.*/$path/" cluster.sh
```

Or what is the easiest shell script language to just expand variables without problems?
Are there any force expand options?

Answer (score 1):

The variable is expanded; the problem is that the value contains characters that `sed` treats as syntax. `sed` sees the command

```
39s/.*//backup//
```

One solution when trying to build a `sed` command dynamically like this is to know ahead of time what characters the variable will include, and use a different delimiter in the `sed` command.

```
sed -i "39s|.*|$path|" cluster.sh
```

Another solution is, if you can control the value of `$path`, is to pre-escape the problem characters.

```
path='\/backup\/'
sed -i "39s/.*/$path/" cluster.sh  # 39/.*/\/backup\//
```